# Laravel Ajax call url to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am new in laravel. I want to create an api using laravel using ajax call. But I request ajax call,url shows invalid server path.
Here is my code
My Route file :

```
Route::get("a/b","AController@c");
```

My js file :

```
var base = "public/index.php";
var url = base + "a/b";
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  dataType: "json",
  timeout: 10000,
  error:function(){  alert("Error getting from server") }
}).done(function(resp){

});
```

Suppose I am in following urls:

```
domain.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/c/d
```

Then I call this ajax , then url will redirect to

```
domain.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/c/public/index.php/a/b
```

Here lar is my laravel app folder

```
** Note I am using NGINX server. My Server Admin do not rewrite this url. That's why I use public/index.php **
```

Comment: Try this code Route::get("/a/b","AController@c"); instead of Route::get("a/b","AController@c");

Comment: This route will not working because my app folder is lots of sub folder after domain. ex- domain.com/dev/{laravel app folder}

Comment: why you use domain.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/c/d not domain.com/dev/lar/public/c/d.  you make index.php a directory not a file???

Comment: domain.com/dev/lar/public/c/d gives 404 error. after giving domain.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/c/d, routes works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing in controller declaration. You have to use backslash at first. For example

```
Route::get("/a/b","AController@c");
```

And in your ajax code url should be

```
var base = "domain.com/dev/lar/public/index.php";
var url = base + "/a/b";
```

Comment: I think the problem was in your base url of ajax. I have updated the code. try this

Comment: You are right. I knew this method. but I do not want to fix my server base path in my code. it's a bad practice to fix base url path in code. If I change my domain, then I want to modify my code